# How to zip a file with a new name in shell script?

Tags: shell, zip

I am trying following command:

```
 zip -rm /home/foo/bar/example.zip /home/foo/bar/example.csv
```

But when I extract example.zip I found directories too. Like /home/foo/bar/example.csv

How can I get without directories. I have to run zip command with full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the option

```
--junk-paths
```

should do what you want.